# Manipulating preg_replaces's 'replace' value

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to alter the match value from `preg_replace` with an uppcase copy but cant seem to figure it out...

I've tried:

```
preg_replace("#\[name=((?:keywords)|(?:description))\]#is", "[name=" . strtoupper($1) . "]" ,$str )
```

and

```
preg_replace("#\[name=((?:keywords)|(?:description))\]#is", "[name={strtoupper($1)}]" ,$str )
```

but none work.

any help is muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `e` modifier as:

```
preg_replace("#\[name=((?:keywords)|(?:description))\]#ise", "'[name='.strtoupper('\\1'). ']'" ,$str )
```

[**Code In Action**](http://www.ideone.com/5l1yg)

Comment: This is deprecated since PHP 5.5 in favor of [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callback function and [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for this.

E.g. (untested):

```
preg_replace(
    "#\[name=((?:keywords)|(?:description))\]#is",
    create_function('$matches', 'return "[name=" . strtoupper($matches[1]) . "]"'),
    $str
)
```